# CellularAutomaton's Plot Range

Tags: plotting, cellular-automata

I want to control the plot range of `CellularAutomaton` to show both left and right sides when using rule 60.

Currently I have this:

[image]

But I want to have something like this:

[image]

Code:

```
 Manipulate[
 Graphics[ArrayPlot[CellularAutomaton[60, {{1}, 0}, t]], 
 PlotRange -> {{-100, 100}, {0, 100}}], {t, 0, 30, 1}]
```

Answer (score 4):

[`CellularAutomaton / Region Specifications / #3`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CellularAutomaton.html)

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics[ArrayPlot[CellularAutomaton[60, {{1}, 0}, {t, All}]], 
  PlotRange -> {{-100, 100}, {0, 100}}], {t, 0, 30, 1}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I'd do:

```
Manipulate[
    ArrayPlot[PadLeft[#, 2 (t + 1)] & /@ CellularAutomaton[60, {{1}, 0}, t], Mesh -> True],
  {t, 0, 30, 1}]
```

[image]

(because I didn't look into the docs like [Kuba](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/135313/22013)).

Comment: Wow, great solution.  BTW, do you have an idea how to eliminate the wobbling in the middle?

Comment: That's just a .gif I made to show it here; the `Manipulate` looks ok.